# USART6 STM32F746NG isn't working

Tags: stm32, uart, hal-library, stm32f7

I'm having trouble configuring the USART6 in my STM32F746NG. I am setting up the USART6 to enable UART comunication, using the code below to initiate it and also create an echo function.

```
    __USART6_CLK_ENABLE();


GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7;
GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.Alternate = GPIO_AF8_USART6;
GPIO_InitStructure.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStructure.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

static UART_HandleTypeDef s_UARTHandle;

s_UARTHandle.Instance        = USART6;
s_UARTHandle.Init.BaudRate   = 115200;
s_UARTHandle.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
s_UARTHandle.Init.StopBits   = UART_STOPBITS_1;
s_UARTHandle.Init.Parity     = UART_PARITY_NONE;
s_UARTHandle.Init.HwFlowCtl  = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
s_UARTHandle.Init.Mode       = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
HAL_USART_Init(&s_UARTHandle);

  char generic_buffer;

    for (;;)
{
  HAL_UART_Receive(&s_UARTHandle,generic_buffer,1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&s_UARTHandle,generic_buffer, sizeof(generic_buffer), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

}
```

But the code is not working, is there something missing in the configuration? I'm using the same code that worked in my STM32F407VG, changing the USART name and pins.

Comment: Just a quick guess based on the code I see -- have you also enabled clocks for the GPIOC peripheral?

Comment: something else I noticed, you've got the TX pin set as OD; this is not normal for a UART. You also don't say WHAT isn't working, so my ability to help is limited by your lack of information.

Comment: I also notice that you are not passing the *address* of the (one byte) buffer. You should be using HAL_UART_Receive(&h, &generic_buffer, sizeof(generic_buffer), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

Comment: I mean that I'm not receiving anything from the MCU using the app Real term to proove the UART com, nonetheless the same GPIO configuration changing the UART name and also the pin numbers and port worked in my STM32F407VG

Comment: It's done mates, thanks for your help I forgot to initialize the clock for the GPIOC

Comment: @AlejandroEnriqueGarciaNavar consider updating your question to include the solution so others can find this helpful in the future.

Comment: Also the size in the declaration was missing too, I change it for `char generic_buffer [2]`